# Using jQuery noty within CodeIgniter view for flashdata (page reload)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have been searching for ages but to no avail. I am trying to use jQuery noty in order to give failure notifications (instead of the standard Bootstrap notifications I have been using). I cannot for the life of me get how this is supposed to work. I want the notification to appear based on there being an error in the flashdata...

I am still very much in the learning stages of JavaScript / jQuery so its probably a dumb newbie mistake, I would appreciate any assistance that can be rendered!

Controller:

```
elseif ($usr_result['status'] == FALSE) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('flashError', 'User not active, please contact your administrator');
    redirect('account/login');
}
```

View:

```
<?if($this->session->flashdata('flashError')):?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.noty.defaults.killer = true;

        noty({
            text: '<?=$this->session->flashdata('flashError')?>',
            layout: 'top',
            type: 'error',
            closeButton: ['true']});
     </script>

<?endif?>
```

I have tested noty with a pressbutton:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary noty" data-noty-options='{"text":"This is an alert","layout":"top","type":"alert","closeButton":"true"}'><i class="halflings-icon white bell"></i> Bottom Full Width with Close Button</button>
```

and it works fine (so jQuery and noty are both loaded correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve it, but after researching JavaScript (theres nowhere near enough documentation on noty to be anywhere near helpful for someone who isn't a JavaScript pro), I ended up doing this in my view to get it to work:

```
<?if($this->session->flashdata('flashError')):?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function notify() {
        noty({
            text: '<?=$this->session->flashdata('flashError')?>',
            layout: 'top',
            type: 'error',
            closeButton: true,
            timeout: false
        });
    }
    window.onload = notify;
</script>
<?endif?>
```